# Java Item [] itemList;

Tags: java, arrays

The three class are Purchase, Invoice and Item

Code of list the item name and total price is in Purchase.

```
public class Invoice {

    private String invNumber;
    private Item [] itemList;
    private int itemCount;

    public Invoice(String invNumber, int itemNum) {
        this.invNumber = invNumber;
        itemList = new Item[itemNum];
        itemCount = 0;
    }

    public String getInvNumber() {
        return invNumber;
    }

    public Item[] getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    public Item getItem(int index) {
        return itemList[index];
    }

    public void addItem(String productCode, double price, int quantity) {
        if (itemCount < itemList.length) {
            Item i = new Item(productCode, price, quantity);
            itemList[itemCount] = i;
            itemCount++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to add new item; max already");
        }
    }
}
```

I konw that " Type [] Name "

**but why it can be " Item [] itemList "**

Is it an array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array. `Item[] itemList`, `Item itemList[]`, `Item [] itemList`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the variable `itemList` is of type `Item[]` wich means it points to an array of `Item` objects.

For further reading take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html